# how to bust @providesModule cache

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm building a REST API that will live in AWS Lambda. I'm using [apex](https://github.com/apex/apex) to deploy it, and since I'm implementing it in javascript, I'm using webpack and babel to get my ES6+ goodies. I've discovered a problem with respect to `@providesModule` names, and I haven't been able to work around it.

I just created a new lambda function, and when I compile it, I can see from the output that one module couldn't be found -- but the other one can. Here's a sketch of the filesystem:

```
functions
   ├─ database.js        @providesModule Database -- this works
   ├─ configuration.js   @providesModule MyConfig -- this does not work
   ├── entity-post
          ├── index.js   imports both 'Database' & 'MyConfig'
```

When I compile the lambda, the output indicates that the `MyConfig` dependency couldn't be resolved, but that `Database` could be. I've tried replacing the content of `configuration.js` with dead-simple code, in case resolution is failing on a basic parse error; no luck. I should add that I've got 5 other lambda functions in the same project that use similar imports, and they all work great.

I assume this is some kind of caching problem: the module resolution system hasn't noticed the `@providesModule` inside `configuration.js`.

How do I clear that cache? For that matter, which piece of software is even handling these resolutions? I've tried looking around online, but it's not clear whether recognition of `@providesModule` is a webpack thing, or a babel thing, or a webpack-babel-loader thing, or maybe just a node v5 thing.

---

I've done a lot of digging, both online and within my project's codebase. Here's what I've learned:

Almost all of the links you'll see online about `@providesModule` are about react or react-native projects. That's because Facebook's tooling -- specifically HasteMap (I think), part of the react-native packager suite -- explicitly adds support for `@providesModule`. My project is neither react nor react-native, and it doesn't use any Facebook tools in the build process. My project uses webpack v1.14 and babel v6.22 to build the source.

I've found the error message within webpack's source, at `./node_modules/webpack/lib/dependencies/WebpackMissingModule.js`:

```
exports.moduleCode = function(request) {
    return "var e = new Error(" + JSON.stringify("Cannot find module \"" + request + "\"") + "); " +
        "e.code = 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'; " +
        "throw e;";
};
```

Webpack seems to have a term for scripts that declare a module name in this way: 'Labeled Modules'. There are several scripts within webpack's source that deal with labeled modules, but I haven't been able to pin down the code that recognizes a label within a module. My assumption is that the problem exists in the part of the system that populates the module registry, and the labeled module code I've found all seems to be related to *accessing* those modules within the (already populated) registry.

It's hard to trace this much further within webpack's source code, which is understandably very meta, and distributed across a bajillion files.

Any help troubleshooting this, or links to relevant documentation or framework code that shows how `@providesModule` is handled, is appreciated. I want to understand why my new module isn't resolving, so I can fix that problem. If my caching theory is off-base, fine.

Comment: I assume that you are using [fbjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fbjs). Am I right?

Comment: @fumi_hwh Nope. "My project is neither react nor react-native, and it doesn't use any Facebook tools in the build process." No results for `find . -iname "*fbjs*"`.

Comment: Then I don't get how do you use `@providesModule`. Maybe the problem is why `import 'Database'` works.

Comment: @fumi_hwh: you pose an interesting question. Perhaps digging into that will yield the answer. Will see what I can find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not come as a surprise to most, but webpack doesn't (currently) honor `@providesModule` directives.

The reason it appeared as though it did is that webpack seems to flatten case when doing filename comparisons, and my filenames generally match the labels that I give them:

- database.js == `@providesModule Database`
- assemble.js == `@providesModule Assemble`

The reason I ran into trouble is that configuration.js != `@providesModule MyConfig`.

This also means the question I asked originally was off-base, in that I assumed resolution was failing because labels were being cached, when in fact labels were being ignored. Facebook's HasteMap may indeed use a cache, but it wasn't the culprit here.

Comment: Will you use fbjs then? It would be convenient to use @providesModule, but at this point I don't have an idea how to make it work with Webpack.

Comment: @jrwm No, I won't use `fbjs`. I'd love to add support to webpack, but I'm not sure it's behavior in this respect can be modified through existing customization. The existing "resolver" engine assumes that resolution is a matter of matching import strings against a set of file paths. It seems that making this work would require scanning every file in the watched tree for `@providesModule` declarations, and then registering found aliases in a place that a custom resolver can access. Sadly, I find the organization of WP too obscure to make the attempt.